# Finding index value from list of ipywidget boxes

Tags: python, list, ipywidgets

I have created a series of ipywidget Textboxes (which I use in a form for entry). I am trying to find out the index position for a given .value

if I have a list of 5 Names I know  I can type :

```
 dd_list[5].value
```

to get the value of the textbox on row 6.

I need to reverse the formula to get the row number/index value of a given .value

Its not as simple as getting elements index position from a list as my list stores all the ipywidget textbox information and I have to type .value to isolate the "value" field in textbox

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this myself - didnt quite realise it would be so simple

```
for i in range(len(dd_list)):
    if dd_list[i].value =='VALUE I WANT THE ROW NUMBER FOR':
        print(i)
```